# grant access to premium content on a rails app from an external proxy server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We want to grant automatic access to premium content (that is ordinarily password protected)  to student client requests coming via their university's proxy server.

Any ideas on how to go about this for a ruby on rails app?

Comment: is it safe to use just the remote ip address alone?  - Are there any other identification variables that a proxy server routinely adds to the client request -  in the request header perhaps - that could be used for authentication?

Comment: another issue, when the students are logging in to the university system from outside, is there some way we can automatically authenticate them if they access our site. Their remote ip address then would not be the university's, right? We are not sure how these institution proxy servers work. Is there a way to check that the request is ultimately coming from the proxy server?

Comment: Anyone know what this header variable is used for?

request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Can it be used to determine if the request is coming via the proxy server, even if the proxy server is accessed remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check *request.remote_ip* and make a decision to skip authorization (if thats what you are asking)